# Invoke matlab script from command line multiple times on the same Matlab instance

Tags: matlab

I have a non-matlab program, which invokes a matlab script many times. 
However, each time the matlab script is invoked, firstly matlab workstation needs to be started and then it interprets the script.

Question:

Is there a way to initialize the matlab workstation once, followed by multiple invokes of the matlab script?

Experiment:

On Mac OSX, a simple test running the following command in terminal:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop < test_matlab.m
```

test_matlab.m

```
1 + 1
```